# includeJsFiles not working in fluid ViewHelper in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

I need to add a custom js file in my backend module of TYPO3 v7.6 extension.I added the following code in my layout

```
<f:be.container includeJsFiles="{0:'{f:uri.resource(path:\'Js/Main.js\')}'}">
  <!------------  Contents    ------------>
</f:be.container>
```

No error  but the js file is not included in page source.Any other method is there to implement my requirement?

Answer (score 3):

I would assume the path to the JS-file is wrong.
With your declaration it is expected to be `EXT:your_extension/Resources/Public/Js/Main.js` in your extension (as statet in the core sources).
But when in doubt I would try some other pathes. (full references)

Comment: ```f:uri.resource``` adds the path to the Resources Public automatical. So you must only define the Path from ```Resources/Public```. Your file should so in ```my_extension/Resources/Public/Js/Main.js``` please be aware of uppercase / lowercase.

Comment: I got the js when i put like <script src="{f:uri.resource(path:'Js/Main.js')}" > So path is not wrong

Comment: just for testing: try to invalidate the outer VH, so it will not be rendered. (e.g. `<no-be:container ... >` ) so you see what the inner VH resulted in. Then 2nd replace the inner VH with a static text, first try: `EXT:your_extension/Resources/Public/Js/Main.js`, second: `typo3conf/ext/your_extension/Resources/Public/Js/Main.js`